# I want to control about markdown list

Tags: html, markdown, jekyll

I want to know how I control markdown list.

I write markdown like this:

```
---
layout: post
title:  "06. Testing"
date:   2019-05-17 11:37:00 +0900
category: Rapid Development
---
1. Testing about Markdown's list<br>
Blah blah<br>
Blah blah<br>
<br>
Blah blah<br>
Here we go<br>
 - First list<br>
 - Second list<br>
<br>
Blah blah<br>
Blah blah<br>
<br>
Blah blah<br>
Blah blah
```

then output is https://blogfiles.pstatic.net/MjAxOTA1MTdfNTEg/MDAxNTU4MDYxMDMyODI5.wwfXDWv6zRe18584kvyxJODsd4z8xWzbAp-9Csp4O_Ig.04n28Dl_ufj9NvVaffnQtT0djxqFuhfCnWcxB696yWYg.PNG.burnnine3/temp.png

I want the paragraph below the Second list to belong to the parent li tag, not the ul tag.

So, like this

```
<ol>
  <li>Testing about Markdown’s list<br>
  Blah blah<br>
  Blah blah<br>
  <br>
  Blah blah<br>
  Here we go<br>
  <ul>
    <li>First list</li>
    <li>Second list</il>
  </ul><br>
  Blah blah<br>
  Blah blah<br>
  <br>
  Blah blah<br>
  Blah blah
  </li>
</ol>
```

What kind of ways are there?

Comment: That is not supported by Markdown. As a reminder, Markdown is a subset of HTML. For anything you can;t do in Markdown, you can use raw HTML.

Comment: As a side note, you don't need to manually write `<br>` to create a line break. Just end your line with two or more spaces.

Comment: Thank you guys! Based on the information you gave me, I solved it.